# Checkout via authorize.net AcceptJS it will include https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.min.js

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2.2, authorize.net

When checkout via authorize.net AcceptJS it will include https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.min.js, which return 404.
While it should include https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js

Comment: Are you working on production mode?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this
SANDBOX

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://jstest.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js"
    charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

PRODUCTION

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js"
    charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

Comment: its working fine on Developer mode but when changed to Production its make "https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js" to "https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.min.js" which return 404.

Comment: actually, this is product URL https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js is

Comment: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html